# Android & Accont Kit: Set default language

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, account-kit

I'm trying to set a default language in account kit screens in my Android App, and following the docs I'm setting it on app/build.gradle file:

```
resConfigs "pt-rBR"
```

But it's not working, because when the user has another language as the system language, the Account Kit screens always use the system language.
Is there a way to define just one specific language for my account kit screens, and ignore the system language?

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity or Application you can do the following to 'force' the Locale if you know the user's Locale is not supported. This would be one way of 'swapping' the default Locale.

Configuration localeConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
  localeConfig.locale = Locale.FRENCH; 
  getResources().updateConfiguration(localeConfig, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
But you would have to be careful to only do this if the Locale.getDefault() is known to not be supported and thus the AccountKit default (English) would be shown.